# Android Timer is firing twice

Tags: timer, android, timertask

I am trying to update TextView content every second using Timer Class. Given below is my code. The problem is that the value is increasing by 2 not by 1. Please tell me what the problem is.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void onButtonClick (View view) {
        // calendar 
        OnDateSetListener datelistener = new OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int Year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                ....
                reScheduleTimer(); // starting the timer
            }
        };
    }

    public void reScheduleTimer(){
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new myTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000);
    }
    public class myTimerTask extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            elapsed = elapsed + 1;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
             public void run() {
                    TextView seconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
                    seconds.setText("seconds so far "+elapsed);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add logs or try to debug and get why it is executing timer twice..or why the value in increasing

Comment: this problem in "onDateSetListener" which is called twice not in your timer if you wan try to check put debug on  "onDateSetListener" and check which date picker bug.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But if the timer is supposed to fire after 1000 milliseconds, how come the variable is incremented twice? That is the only place the variable is incremented in my whole project. How do I debug a timer event?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't hurt to check if `timerTask` is null at the beginning of `reScheduleTimer` and cancel it if it is not null.

At the beginning of reScheduleTimer:

```
    if(timerTask != null) {
        timerTask.cancel();
    }
```

Comment: timerTask is not null. I have put all those checks already :)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how the variable is increasing by more than 1, but I solved the problem by reading the system clock on every invocation of the function and displaying it.